# Cabal build Caradano-cli Cardano-node error

Tags: cabal, linux

I'm trying to create a Cardano staking pool on a raspberry pi 4 with 8GB of RAM. I've been following the coin cashew tutorial for staking pools: https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node#1-install-cabal-and-ghc

I finally got the cabal build for `cardano-cli` and `cardano-node`. I have also checked that ghc is on `8.10.4` but for some reason getting this error:

```
ghc: could not execute: opt
cabal: Failed to build Diff-0.4.0 (which is required by
test:cardano-cli-golden from cardano-cli-1.29.0). See the build log above for
details.
Failed to build Only-0.1 (which is required by test:cardano-node-test from
cardano-node-1.29.0, exe:cardano-node from cardano-node-1.29.0 and others).
See the build log above for details.
Failed to build StateVar-1.2.1 (which is required by test:cardano-node-test
from cardano-node-1.29.0, exe:cardano-node from cardano-node-1.29.0 and
others). See the build log above for details.
Failed to build Win32-network-0.1.0.0 (which is required by
test:cardano-node-test from cardano-node-1.29.0, exe:cardano-node from
cardano-node-1.29.0 and others). See the build log above for details.
Failed to build abstract-par-0.3.3 (which is required by
test:cardano-node-test from cardano-node-1.29.0, exe:cardano-node from
cardano-node-1.29.0 and others). See the build log above for details.
```

Comment: The logs it's telling you to read are the same ones we'd need to read to be of any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to compile the code on raspberrypi. It takes 7+ hours.
Use the prebuilt binaries from armada-alliance.
https://github.com/armada-alliance/cardano-node-binaries/tree/main/static-binaries
Join the telegram channel

Answer (score 0):

Find some resources and prebuilt binaries for arm here.
armada-alliance.com